# Regex to find a specific string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to find the word "Amount" within the following list of words:

```
WaterAmount 
DamageAmount 
AmountOwed
```

I tried to use regex, but the following doesn't work:

```
Regex.IsMatch(name, @"\Amount\")
```

Can someone please help me to figure out how to do this?

Thank you.

**Update:**

Code being used:

```
foreach (string name in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(name, "Amount"))
            {
                Response.Write(Request.Form[name]);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Not working\n");
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: looks like this doesn't even need any Regex stuff.

Comment: Why do you need regex? You can just do `foo.Contains("Amount")`

Comment: I tried contains and that didn't work

Comment: @BradHazelnut, that makes no sense. Those strings contain "Amount"???

Comment: Try taking out the `\\`s.

Comment: Provide more example code of what you tried. This is probably an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I am trying the following                                                  foreach (string name in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            
            if (Regex.IsMatch(name, "Amount"))
            {
                Response.Write(Request.Form[name]);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Not working\n");
            }
            
        }                                                                                                  I also tried if (name.Contains("Amount")) and that didn't work either

Comment: I put it in the original question

Comment: Modify this:  `Response.Write("Not working\n");` to `Response.Write(string.Format("\"{0}\" - did not match", name));` and update your question with the output.

Comment: I found the problem with that, thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using regex, use:

```
name.Contains("Amount")
```

this should return a boolean as to whether Amount is in the string.

You don't need regex for this situation (and sometimes it's good to go without when unnecessary)

as others suggested,

```
name.IndexOf("amount", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

could also be used to include "AMOUNT", "amount", "AmOunT", etc.

Or:

```
name.IndexOf("amount", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)!= -1
```

We're just checking that IndexOf doesn't send back -1 for 'not found'.

The reason you might not want to use:

```
name.ToLower().Contains("amount")
```

is because it will have problems with international characters (accents, etc).
If you were passing in a variable that could have any text, that could pose a problem. 
For a case with a constant string, it might be fine, however (though not extremely recommended)

Edit:

If I understand C# correctly (not my expertise, though i've used it), this should work:

```
foreach (string name in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if (name.IndexOf("amount", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Form[name]);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Not working\n");
    }
}
```

I see an extra brace in your code. Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: `name.IndexOf("amount", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0` is better for case insensitive `Contains`. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/393487)

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is correct. I would suggest one minor change for it to work...

```
Regex.IsMatch(name, @"Amount")
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = name.IndexOf("Amount", 0, name.Length);
```

This will get you the [index of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d93tkzah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the first occurrence. If you want all of them, just loop trough the text.

To ignore case sensitivity;

```
var index = name.IndexOf("Amount", 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

And if there's no match, `IndexOf` returns -1.

If you just want to know if your string is in there, use `.Contains()`.